# Linux can see all of my WIndows 7 partition?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, windows-7

Is it normal for my Windows 7 partition to be completely visible from Ubuntu? When In Windows 7 it cannot see any of the Linux partition, just its own partition.

I am a little worried something hasnt been set up correctly.

Comment: This is really useful when, for some reason, you cannot boot in Windows and you need to backup your data. Even if you don't have a linux installation you can boot a LiveCD and save all the documents you care before formatting the computer and installing a linux distro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is normal.

Ubuntu recognizes an incredible lot of filesystems and can read them (mostly write them too).

Windows recognizes only it's own FAT and NTFS, if we don't consider the filesystems of optical media.

That is the reason why Windows cannot read Ubuntu partitions, but that Ubuntu can read and write any Windows partition without any problem. There exist some projects like [Ext2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) or [zfs-win](http://code.google.com/p/zfs-win/) which bring partial support for some filesystems to Windows.

Comment: Many thanks LiveWireBT, your edit is highly appreciated. The answer looks a lot better now.

Answer (score 0):

It **is fine**.

From Ubuntu you should be able to see your Windows partitions (if any).

From Windows, you are not able to view Linux partitions (`ext2` nor `ext4`) because Microsoft did not include support for these file systems.

Comment: you forgot `ext3` :P

Comment: Totally, and also `ext` (the first one) :D